# BeautifulSoup Python web scraping Missing html Main Body

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am using Beutifull soup to scrape this web page: https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com//#results-dog/race_id=1765914&dog_id=527442&r_date=2020-03-19&track_id=61&r_time=11:03

Result: i get the javaScript, Css

Desired output: i need the main html

i used this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com//#results-dog/race_id=1765914&dog_id=527442&r_date=2020-03-19&track_id=61&r_time=11:03'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)url = 'https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com//#results-dog/race_id=1765914&dog_id=527442&r_date=2020-03-19&track_id=61&r_time=11:03'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m afraid you won’t be able to get it directly using BeautifulSoup because the page loads then a javascript loads data.

It’s one of the component’s limitations, you may need to use selenium.

please check the answers on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking for is this:

```
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

It will contain the text from the page including html tags